# Is there a way of fine tuning palm rejection settings of libinput?

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 on a Lenovo Yoga Pro 2. For a while Ubuntu switched to `libinput` from `synaptics`. I am happy with `libinput` in general, except its palm rejection & "disable-touchpad-while-typing" is not working really well.

I couldn't find any kind of documentation to adjust these, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, at this time, it seems you cannot fine-tune palm rejection settings.

https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/index.html This link shows the architecture libinput uses on both Wayland and X11.

On Wayland, you need to use your compositor. For example, if you're using Weston (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/weston.ini.5.html), it seems the only option it exposes is "enables tap to click on touchpad devices". If you're using X11, you can use xinput to configure your libinput device (www.mepis.org/docs/en/index.php?title=Configuring_the_touchpad_with_xinput).

Looking at the libinput API (wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/group__config.html), it seems no functions are available to fine-tune DWT (disable while typing). Therefore, not only do the fine-tuning settings need to be exposed but the functions need to be created to do the fine-tuning.